# How to search across indexes and types?

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider I store the  document under Elastic Search.

Search across types

Here is my url(`http://localhost:9200/bookstore/books/1001`) for creating book with id as 1001(1001 is primary key from DB) and below
is the document

```
    {
      "title": "Java 8 Optional In Depth",
      "category":"Java",
      "published_date":"23-FEB-2017",
      "author":"Rambabu Posa"

     }
```

Similarly I create the pen index with URL `http://localhost:9200/bookstore/pen/2001` and document below

```
     {
      "name": "Parker",
      "category":"Ink",
      "buy_date":"15-Mar-2017",
      "price":"20"

     }
```

If I need to search across the types(books and pen both) under any field under index `bookstore` Can I do  it with `http://localhost:9200/bookstore/_search?q=:any_keyword` ?

**Search across indexes**

Can I do it with `http://localhost:9200/_search?q=:any_keyword` ?

Comment: What you're exactly looking for ?  Because you can simply perform a http://localhost:9200/_search to search across types and indices.

Comment: I need to search for specific keyword across 1) indexes and 2) across types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://localhost:9200/_search` is the right endpoint to search across all indices and types, but the field is missing in `q=:any_keyword`. See [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-search.html#search-multi-index-type) — something like `q=my_field:any_keyword`. If you want to search all the fields, you can [use the `_all` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping-all-field.html#querying-all-field) with `q=any_keyword`.

However, you don't really want to do this / some other remarks:

1. Generally switch to the [request body search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/search-request-body.html) — it has all the features and will be what you want to use in the long run.
2. The [`_all` field has been deprecated in 6.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/mapping-all-field.html#mapping-all-field); either use the explicit `copy_to` or specify the specific field(s) you want to search.
3. Multiple types per index are disabled by default in 6.0. Change your mapping to use a single type.
4. Searching across all indices can be rather expensive. If you can, specify one index to search; alternatively you can also define wildcards (`http://localhost:9200/foo*/_search`) or a list of indices (`http://localhost:9200/foo,bar,baz/_search`).